# Perl: long string conversion to comma delimited list of bytes

Tags: perl

I want to convert `ABCDEF` to `A,B,C,D,E,F`

What is the fastest way to do this using **Perl**?

I have lots of strings to convert and the strings can be up to 32768 bytes long.  So, I want to lower the overhead from the string conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
$string =~ s/.\K(?=.)/,/g;       # using \K keep escape
$string =~ s/(?<=.)(?=.)/,/g;    # pure lookaround assertion
```

Or

```
$string = join ",", split(//, $string);
```

To find the fastest solution, use [`Benchmark`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark).

**Extra credit:**

This is the result of a benchmark I tried. Surprisingly, the `\K` escape is much faster than the pure lookaround, which is about as fast as the split/join.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $string = "ABCDEF" x 1000;

cmpthese(-1, { 
    keep       => 'my $s = $string; $s =~ s/.\K(?=.)/,/g',
    lookaround => 'my $s = $string; $s =~ s/(?<=.)(?=.)/,/g',
    splitjoin  => 'my $s = $string; $s = join ",", split(//, $string)' 
});
```

**Output:**

```
                 Rate  splitjoin lookaround       keep
splitjoin   6546367/s         --        -6%       -47%
lookaround  6985568/s         7%         --       -44%
keep       12392841/s        89%        77%         --
```

Comment: Seem to always submit at same time...  Good answer.

Comment: @Lucas Thank you. Yes, competition is fierce sometimes.

Comment: `unpack '(a)*'` is faster than `split //`, but not enough to overtake "keep".

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -le 'print join(",", unpack("(A)*", "hello"))'
h,e,l,l,o

$ perl -le 'print join(",", unpack("C*", "hello"))'
104,101,108,108,111

$ perl -le 'print join(",", unpack("(H2)*", "hello"))'
68,65,6c,6c,6f
```

Comment: I like these ones. I thought in the `unpack` function but not used to it. And seems pretty fast. **+1**

Comment: @Birei, the `(A)*` version is less than half as fast as keep, by my run of `cmpthese`.  I'm still wondering if broncofan7 really wants the letters, though, since he says 'bytes'.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";

my @chars = $str =~ /./sg;

print join ",", @chars;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print strings with lower overhead, you may want to just print the string while you parse it, rather than doing the whole transformation in memory, i.e.

```
while (m/(.)\B/gc){
 print "$1,";
};
if (m/\G(.)/) {
  print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: `\B` is clever, but only if punctuation and other word boundary characters do not appear in the string.

Comment: Yeah, if the strings aren't as simple as in the question, they might need to delay printing each letter until the next letter is seen, so they could chop the , off the last one and print it.  The m/(.)/g approach should still be adaptable, though.